# Displaying n'th level category in php

Tags: php

below is my SQL table

```
id   parent_id

1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1
5      3
6      5
```

i want to display n'th level hierarchic relation in array like below

```
array
{
  1
    sub{
         3
           sub{
               5
           }
         4
        }
 }
```

and so on

how can i do this in PHP

Comment: i have to achieve n'th level relation dynamically,

Comment: @vsmdk you will have too use recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first select all your root categories with parent id 0 and pass their ids to this recursive function

```
function getChildCats($catId)
{
    $sql = "select * from categories where parent_id = $cateID";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $raws[];  
    while($raw = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $raw['sub'] =  getChildCats($raw['id'])
        $raws[] = $raw;
    }
    return $raws;
}
```

Comment: Recursively executing SQL queries? Seems pretty inefficient to me.

Comment: @nickb me too ... but it was what popped first in mind and don't know how actually write such query that can serves the purpose . can you explore ?